# Decomposing the permutation representation of $S_{4}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $U$ be the trivial representation of $S_{4}$ and $V$ be the standard representation (of $S_{4}$). Why is it that $\mathbb{C}^{4} = U \oplus V$? I see that this is true by character theory, but is there a way to show it without character theory?

Comment: You probably should define your terms more precisely. I presume you mean the natural permutation module when you mentioned $\mathbb{C}^4.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to see this, assuming you do mean the natural permutation representation by $\mathbb{C}^4$, is that the permutation matrices are unitary matrices. There is an obvious $1$-dimenional invariant subspace $U$, conisting of (say column) vectors with al coordinats equal. The action of $S_4$ on this space is trivial. Since permutation matrices are unitary, the orthogonal complement $U^{\perp}$ of $U$ with respect to the usual inner product is a ($3$-dimensional) invariant subspace, and we have $\mathbb{C}^4 = U \oplus U^{\perp}.$